# How to change the blue foreground color of text in PHPStorm?

Tags: color-theme, phpstorm

How to change the blue foreground color of text in **PHPStorm** IDE?

I would like to be a **Cyan** color (`#00B0F6`).

[image]

Comment: What did your research tell you? [Configuring Colors and Fonts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need changing color in the `File Status` page of the Colors and Fonts settings: `Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | File Status`, `Modified`. 
Make sure to press **Save As** button first, as predefined schemes can't be changed, you need creating a local copy to be able to customize colors.